# Why PHPMailer showing Failed to move file error message?

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am sending email using PHPMailer from localhost. I am using attachment option to send image with email. But It's showing me following error message :

**Error Message :**

```
Failed to move file to C:\Users\Work Station\AppData\Local\Temp\3c3D24E.tmp
```

**My code :**

```
require '../PHPMailerAutoload.php';
$m =  new PHPMailer();

$m->isSMTP();
$m->SMTPAuth = true;
//$m->SMTPDebug = 2;

$m->Host = gethostbyname('smtp.gmail.com');
$m->Username = 'username';
$m->Password = 'password';
$m->SMTPSecure =  'ssl';
$m->Port = 465;

$m->From = 'support@from.com';
$m->FromName = 'Shibbir Ahmed';
$m->addReplyTo($to);
$m->addAddress($to, 'Shibbir Ahmed');

//Attach multiple files one by one
if(isset($_FILES['userfile'])) {
    for ($ct = 0; $ct < count($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']); $ct++) {
        $uploadfile = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), sha1($_FILES['userfile']['name'][$ct]));
        $filename = $_FILES['userfile']['name'][$ct];
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'][$ct], $uploadfile)) {
            $m->addAttachment($uploadfile, $filename);
        } else {
            echo  'Failed to move file to ' . $uploadfile;
        }
    }
}

$m->Subject = $subject;
$m->Body = $message;
$m->AltBody = strip_tags($message, "<p>, <br>");
```

Comment: It is showing the error because attachment can not be saved in particular location. Reason might be the not enough directory permission to store attachments.

Comment: can you tell me output of this  $uploadfile = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), sha1($_FILES['userfile']['name'][$ct]))

Comment: @Ali I have another page where I am uploading image. It's not showing error message .

Comment: @ramsingh I am giving it

Comment: Its showing me this : C:\Users\Work Station\AppData\Local\Temp\84a389F.tmp

Comment: change your path suppose upload is dir and $uploadfile="/upload" 
  upload 
  your.php use this

Comment: @ramsingh  You are right :)

Answer (score 1):

This means your PHP config (in php.ini) is pointing at a temp directory that it's unable to write to. [`sys_get_tmp_dir()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sys-get-temp-dir.php) points at that location, and you can set it with the `sys_temp_dir` php.ini setting. It may also be worth checking the [`upload_tmp_dir`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-tmp-dir) setting.

You're likely to have problems with other things like session storage too. Either fix the permissions on that location so you do have write access, or point it somewhere that you do have write access to.

Comment: session storage ? Can you tell me details ?

Comment: It's just that file-based session storage (the default in PHP) uses the system tmp dir by default, so if it can't write there (for the same reason move_uploaded_fiel can't), then you will have trouble with sessions.